# How to add --connection parameter to propel:build

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

When there are number of plugins in a project and I need to create model, form and filter classes , i am left with only one option that I need to create classes for all connections. How can I make propel:build to accept --connection parameter such that it builds only the classes for specific connection related to a plugin?

Symfony Version : 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [sfPropelORMPlugin](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin), and according to [the code of the sfPropelBuildAllTask](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/blob/master/lib/task/sfPropelBuildAllTask.class.php#L31), you can use `--connection`. Same thing for the [sfPropelBuildModelTask](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/blob/master/lib/task/sfPropelBuildModelTask.class.php). Thing is, it's not used by these tasks. This is an issue you should report, but at the moment there is no way to use a given connection to build some classes and not all of them.

Comment: But there maybe some way out by modification or extending these classes?

Comment: AFAIK not easily. (disclaimer: I lead the Propel projects)

Comment: We used custom generators to achieve this. Accepting your answer as it was helpful. Thank you very much.